# Duplicate every two lines a variable number of times

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have multiple .fasta files (that are named barcode*_consensus.fasta) that look like this:

```
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
```

I would like to duplicate/repeat every two lines n number of times, as specified after 'total supporting reads'. So for example, I would like to duplicate the first two lines 12 times, the second two lines 6 times, etc.

With awk, I did manage to select every line that starts with '>' and the next line:

```
awk '/>/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]} NR in nr' barcode01_consensus.fasta
```

But I can't find out how to print this n number of times with a variable.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Updated:**
So I would like the final file to look something like:

> |>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
> TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTT

> |>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
> TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTT

> |>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
> TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTT

....x 12 times....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there's a proper bioinformatics toolkit that would do what you want more robustly, but with GNU awk you could match and capture the repeat number like

```
gawk '
  /^>?[|]>/ {
    if((getline seq) > 0) $0 = $0 ORS seq
  } 
  match($0,/total_supporting_reads_([0-9]+)/,a) {
    while(a[1]--) print
  }
' file.fasta
```

You can do the same with non-GNU awk, except that you would need to extract the numeric portion of the match as a substring using the `RSTART` and `RMATCH` values instead of capturing it in an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use space or underscore as the field separator. Then, the count is the 8th field:

```bsh
awk -F'[ _]' '
    $1 ~ /[>|]+consensus$/ {n = $8; print; next}
    {while (--n >= 0) print}
' file
```

output

```
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
```

---

To print each pair of lines *n* times requires just minor changes:

```bsh
awk -F'[ _]' '
    $1 ~ /[>|]+consensus$/ {firstline = $0; n = $8; next}
    {while (--n >= 0) print firstline ORS $0}
' file
```

output

```
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
>|>consensus_cl_id_1018_total_supporting_reads_12 LN:i:1369 RC:i:12 XC:f:1.000000
TCATTAACCACAAAGTGGTGAGCGTTCTCCCGAAGGTTAAACTACCCACTTCTTTTGCAGCCAACTCCCATGGTGTGACGGG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_107_total_supporting_reads_6 LN:i:1440 RC:i:6 XC:f:1.000000
GACTTCAGCCCAGTCATTAGTCCTACCATGGACCCCCATATTACTAGAGGAGCTTCCGATATTACTAACTCCCATGCCGTGACGGGCG
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
|>consensus_cl_id_116_total_supporting_reads_5 LN:i:1314 RC:i:558 XC:f:1.000000
AGAACGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCTACCTTCGGGGGAGCGGCGGACGGGTTAGTAACGCGTGGGAATAT
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for most of it, however, I would like to print both line 1+2 n number of times and this only prints the second line n number of times. I have updated my question to clarify this in a better way.